# Write a custom oracle function to remove chr(10)=linefeed & chr(13)=carriage return and trim column and return the value

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

Is it possible to write a custom oracle function that does the following

```
remove char(10)
remove char(13)
trim
```

so if i write

select custom_function(col1) from tab1 it returns value with linefeed,carriage return and trimmed

```
If possible i also want to replace a long balnk line between two words with single blank.
```

where col1 is string

Can someone please help me in this

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you give us some background regarding why you need to do this?

Comment: so instead of `trim(
        replace(
          replace(str
                 , chr(13),'')
                 , chr(10),'')
                 ) as col1` you want a function?

Answer (score 1):

For the trimming question, you probably just need [`rtrim`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions160.htm), e.g:

```
select rtrim(somecolumn, chr(10)||chr(13)||' ')
from   ( select 'Some text

                ' as somecolumn
         from dual );
```

For replacing multiple whitespace characters you can use [regexp_replace](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions149.htm), e.g:

```
select regexp_replace(somecolumn, '\s{2,}', ' ')
from   ( select 'Some   text' as somecolumn
         from dual );
```

Both together:

```
select regexp_replace(rtrim(somecolumn, chr(10)||chr(13)||' '), '\s{2,}', ' ')
from   ( select 'Some   text

                ' as somecolumn
         from dual );
```